# Neo4j, do nodes without relationships affect performance?

Tags: neo4j

How do nodes without relationships affect performance?

The input stream contains duplicate nodes and once I've determined that a node is not of interest I'd like a short-hand way to know that I've already seen this node and want to disregard it.

If I store one instance of the node in the db without any relationships will it impact performance? Potentially the number of relationship-less nodes is very large.

Comment: What is "very large"?

Comment: Thousands growing to millions. My guess is at some point I'll have to age them out of the database based on time and reference frequency.

Comment: That should be fine, you can delete them regularly as needed then the records will be reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these don't affect performance, they take up space on disk but will not be loaded if you don't access them. And as you don't traverse them it doesn't matter that much.

I would still skip them, you can do it both with `neo4j-import` there is a `--skip-duplicate-nodes` option as well as `LOAD CSV` or Cypher in general, there is the `MERGE` clause which only creates a new node if it is not already there.